# Camel: POST-request routing by URL-pattern

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to catch some POST-request, log a message (and maybe a body or params in future); then pass them further to **booHost**, so the client will get the result of the call:

```
    from("restlet:http://localhost:8090/api/endpointFoo?restletMethod=post")
            .log("oh, it's a message!")
            .routeId("someAPI")
            .to("http://booHost:8090/api/endpointFoo?bridgeEndpoint=true&restletMethod=post");
```

That works just GREAT.

**But**:
What I need is the URL-pattern that will work that way. I'm trying:

```
    from("restlet:http://localhost:8090/api/{endpoint}?restletMethod=post")
            .log("oh, it's a message!")
            .routeId("someAPI")
            .to("http://booHost:8090/api/{endpoint}?bridgeEndpoint=true&restletMethod=post");
```

The **"from"** shots when I make the post. The message is logged.

But **"to"** seems not to treat *{endpoint}* as a param - it treats it like a *constant*; so the result of that call fails.

I don't need hardcoded endpoints because booHost API should be extended in future without Camel changes.

In other words, I need all calls to http://localhost:8090/api/* to be catched and resent to http://booHost:8090/api/* on the same endpoint.

Maybe I should use another component? Or How can I make it this way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @vikingsteve I've started to read about **recipientList**.

I've modified my code according to [this FAQ question](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html)

The final version looks like this:

```
    from("restlet:http://localhost:8090/api/{endpoint}?restletMethod=post")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "POST-request to /${headers.endpoint} was sent")
            .routeId("someAPI")
            .recipientList(simple("http://booHost:8090/api/${headers.endpoint}?bridgeEndpoint=true&restletMethod=post"));
```

It works as suggested.